# how to move anaconda environment?

Tags: anaconda

Well ,a easy question but a little difficult for me .

I changed OS from win10 to win7. I installed lots of external packages on the old version [based on win10],I used the CLONE and CREATE to copy the environment and moved to another disk. Then I install the new OS and anaconda ,copied the backed environment to Anaconda/env/, there's no any YML or YAML file generated . So I need to know how to use the backed environment ?

many thanks.